# PreviewMouseWheel event not passing up to enclosing ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, events, mousewheel

In my WPF application, I have a DataGrid inside of a ScrollViewer.

The mouse wheel properly causes the ScrollViewer to scroll as long as the mouse is hovering over the scroll bar. Once the mouse moves over the included DataGrid, however, the mouse wheel stops causes the ScrollViewer to scroll.

I had thought that events were automatically passed up the tree until an object handled them, but if that is the case, why is the ScrollViewer not handling the PreviewMouseWheel event on its own?

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="200">
            <DataGrid SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="True"
                      AlternationCount="2" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFC2CBFF"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SearchResults}}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no possiblity at the moment to test it, but I think this will help.

```
    private void Grid_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {

        e.Handled = false;
    }
```

Set `e.Handled = false` should do the trick, because it will pass the event to the `FrameworkElement.Parent`.

In the end why wouldn't you use the `ScrollViewer` of your `DataGrid`. Why even wrap another around.

```
<DataGrid ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

I think you get the idea !

Comment: Mostly because I've learned WPF through trial and error rather than a structured program, so I was unaware that DataGrid included a ScrollViewer!